# How we find out a next day in Swift

Tags: swift, date

How do we find out a next day in Swift language? Suppose today is 2014-09-15. How we can find out a date: 2014-09-16.

Comment: Nothing to do with Swift. Don't confuse language with frameworks and their API. Is this iOS? If so, look at NSDateComponents and NSDateFormatter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Swift code without using NSCalendar:

```
var today = NSDate()
var res = today.dateByAddingTimeInterval(24*60*60)
println("\(today), \(res)") // 2014-09-15 10:31:28 +0000, 2014-09-16 10:31:28 +0000
```

Comment: This is dangerous, not every day is 24 hours long… (e.g. when chain gin to day light saving time)

Answer (score 6):

Use `NSDateComponents`:

```
var calendar:NSCalendar = NSCalendar.currentCalendar()      
var dayFutureComponents:NSDateComponents = NSDateComponents()

 dayFutureComponents.day = 1 // aka 1 day

 let today = NSDate.date()  // Sep 15, 2014, 1:10 PM
 var oneDay:NSDate = calendar.dateByAddingComponents(
         dayFutureComponents, toDate: today!, options: nil)!
```

Output:

```
"Sep 16, 2014, 1:10 PM"
```